# How *(&i) dereferencing works in c without pointer pointing?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a=10;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    printf("%d\n",*(&a));
}
```

As variable 'a' is of type integer and not a variable pointer pointing to itself so how dereferencing is working here.
I maybe wrong in understanding.

Comment: `&a` is a pointer, `a` is not.

Answer (score 1):

The unary `&` operator takes the address of its operand.  So the result of `&a` is a pointer of type `int *` which can subsequently be dereferenced via the unary `*` operator.

Comment: “Takes” is not a great verb here. For exampe, `sin` takes an angle and returns its sine. The unary `&` operator produces the address of its operand.

Answer (score 1):

For the property of the unary `&` and `*` operator:

> *The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand*

and

> *The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; **if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the object. If the operand has type "pointer to type", the result has type "type".***

In your case

```
*(&a)
```

is the same as

```
* (pointer to object 'a') or, * (address of variable 'a')
```

which is the same as

```
 a
```

So, this

```
 printf("%d\n",*(&a));
```

is similar to

```
printf("%d\n",a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did the referencing and dereferencing of a pointer at the same time.

By putting asterisk you are dereferencing pointer that is asking for value at the address and inside the `()` you are referencing the variable that is you are replacing the `&a` with the address of the variable after `&` so the address is replaced with the `*` the value at the address is fetched. So it works.